# convert json string to json array - android java

Tags: java, php, android, json

first of all, I've read a ton of similar questions on this site and none has solved my problem so
I have this json file that I create using php  :

```
{
"done":true,
"data":"[
{\"id\":\"5099\",\"user_id\":\"892\"},
{\"id\":\"5100\",\"user_id\":\"892\"}
....
]"}
```

now in java android I want to parse it but it gives me this error: JSON.TypeMismatch
this is my android code to parse the json file:

```
//class from which I get the json in a JSONObject - works fine so far
JSONObject httpResult = itemHttpRequest.get("/fetch?currentList=&sort=recent&extra=");
        try {
            JSONArray httpData = httpResult.getJSONArray("data");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but it keeps giving me error.
is it because the data array in my json file is surrounded by quotes?
please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For sure, `data` is a String (character surrounded by quotes), it can't be read as a JSONArray.

If you can't make your php to generate a JSON array, what you can do on Android size, is to get the `data` string with :

```
String data = httpResult.getString("data");
```

then you can create a JSONARRAY with :

[JSONArray constructor](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray(java.lang.String))

```
JSONArray dataArray = new JSONArray(data)
```

Comment: you sir are a life savor, I wish I could kiss you or something :*

Answer (score 2):

```
"data":"[
{\"id\":\"5099\",\"user_id\":\"892\"},
{\"id\":\"5100\",\"user_id\":\"892\"}
....
]"
```

is a string

But

```
"data":[
{"id":"5099","user_id":"892"},
{"id":"5100","user_id":"892"}
....
]
```

is array

Comment: @user3425760 where are you from take this json?

Answer (score 2):

You are supplying invalid JSON. You need to correct your JSON by removing extra quotes. You can always use some [validator](http://jsonlint.com) to spot these types of problem E.g.

```
{
    "done": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "5099",
            "user_id": "892"
        },
        {
            "id": "5100",
            "user_id": "892"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: yes, i deleted my comment, but the invalid JSON can also comes from \n in the data String

Answer (score 1):

Use this to convert JSON array to string

```
private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        /*
         * To convert the InputStream to String we use the
         * BufferedReader.readLine() method. We iterate until the
         * BufferedReader return null which means there's no more data to
         * read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder and returned as
         * String.
         */
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
  JsonArray array = new  JsonArray(value)
```

value :- Should have proper jsonarray format. otherwise it will throw a JsonException